# Dual space of continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, real-analysis

Let $C_b(\Omega,V )=$ { $ f:\Omega\rightarrow V $ } is the Banach space of all bounded continuous functions in Banach space $V$ with a norm $\|\cdot\|$ defined as $\|f\|_\infty=\sup _{x\in\Omega}\|f(x)\|$. Let $C_b(\Omega)=C_b(\Omega,\mathbb R)$. For a normal topological space $\Omega$ ( $T_4$-space) it holds that

$$
C_b(\Omega)^*=rba(\Omega),
$$

where $rba(\Omega)$ is the space of regular bounded finitely additive measures, and also 
$$
x^*f=\int\limits_{\Omega}f(\omega)\mu(d\omega),\quad f\in C_b(\Omega),\quad x^*\in C_b(\Omega)^*,\quad \mu\in rba(\Omega)
$$

Are there more precise results for the case $C_b (\mathbb R)$? Particularly I'm interested in more "beautiful" presentation of the measure $\mu$.

Comment: The dual of $C_b({\mathbb R})$ is the space of Radon measures on the Stone-Cech compactification of ${\mathbb R}$ -- I don't know if that is beautiful enough. What kinds of result were you hoping to find?

Comment: A related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44183/dual-of-bounded-uniformly-continuous-functions  In particular, Grey Kuperberg's answer makes me skeptical you will get a "good" answer...

Comment: Thank you.
Could you please clarify the form of the functional? Will it be the same?
$$
x^*f=\int\limits_{\beta\mathbb R}f(\omega)\mu(d\omega)
$$

And how we understand $f(\omega)$ when $\omega\in\beta\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb R$?

By the "beautiful" I meant, for example in our case, that functional consists of two parts: integral on $\mathbb R$ and on $\beta\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb R$ (because I don't know about measurability in $\beta\mathbb R$)

Comment: It follows from the universal properties of $\beta{\mathbb R}$ that any continuous bounded function on ${\mathbb R}$ extends uniquely to a continuous function on $\beta{\mathbb R}$, so that is how you define $f(\omega)$. One gets the representing measure $\mu$ by applying the Riesz representation theorem for $C(\beta{\mathbb R})$. If you are asking for an "explicit" description of the representing measure, then I think the question that Matthew Daws links to suggests that this is unlikely

Comment: Thank you very much! This uniqueness of the extension is exactly what I needed. And now I also agree that there isn't "explicit" description. 

Comment: Since the OP is satisfied with the answers given in the comments, I vote to close.

Comment: The only thing I want to figure out, which reference I should give to the fact of the uniqueness of the extension? Because, as I know, the definition of Stone-Cech compactification is based on mapping $X$ to
$[0,1]^C$, where $C$ is the set of all continuous functions from $X$ into $[0,1]$. After that question can be closed.

Comment: Dunford Schwarz